# How to remove parts of an expression

Tags: matrix, expression-manipulation

I have an expression where terms `Transpose[R].R` appear. R is a matrix with the property `Transpose[R].R=IdentityMatrix[3]`.

How do I remove all the sub-expressions of type `Transpose[R].R` from an expression? Example: suppose I have the expression:

```
A.B.Transpose[R].R.C
```

I want to transform it into

```
A.B.C
```

Comment: `/. Transpose[x_].x_ -> Sequence[]`. Have you read the documentation re: patterns, replacement, etc? This is not an interactive documentation answer site :-) Also, avoid using uppercase initials for your symbols - or you're asking for trouble.

Comment: @ciao Fantastic, thanks a lot. Yes, I always ask only after searching the documentation, which did not show Sequence[] where I looked. How did you learn about this command?

Comment: `Sequence` is in the documentation...  and the documentation certainly is not a cookbook for pattern machinations, though it does have copious examples. Best way to learn those kind of things is peruse the docs, find something interesting, and play with it in "what if" kind of ways. I've found that to be most effective teaching others term-rewriting languages like MMA.

Comment: @ciao. Thanks. Can you tell me one last thing. What would I write for `xyz` if I want in `Select[expr,!FreeQ[#,xyz]&]` to select any term of `expr` which contains a pattern `R.(something, don't care what).R`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Incidentally ciao's replacement relies on special evaluation rules for `Dot` due to it having the `Flat` attribute.  This is something in which you should invest the time to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you would like something like this?

```
Select[A.B.Transpose[R].R.T, FreeQ[#, R] &]
```

This mainly used the expression's tree like property. Due to `Dot`'s `Flat` Property, the whole expression will actually looks like `Dot[A,B,Transpose[R],R,T]`, thus this code can generate the result you want:

```
A.B.T
```

Note that I've change your `C` to `T` cause C is a built in symbol.....

Or you may use this if you only want to remove it when Transpose[R] and R are ordered in this particular way:

```
A.B.Transpose[R].R.T //. Dot[x___, Transpose[R], R, y___] -> Dot[x, y]

(*A.B.T*)
```

Comment: Your first method doesn't work on `A.B.R.Transpose[R].R.T`, just on the OP's toy example.

Comment: It worked~ Though a incorrect result as it will delete everthing related to R......